# How to get the mouse position in Android globally

Tags: java, android, c, linux

On an Android platform I have to find out the global mouse position. This means not just in the currently running app. But in any app or in home screen. I have full access to the Android platform. So this could be also some solution in C working on the underlying Linux system.

I know its pretty easy on Linux using xdotool, but unfortunately this relies on Xlib and so on. There is no X server on Android. At least not on mine.

Is there some command I can use or something on the Linux system, where I can read the mouse position?

Thanks,
Eduard

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find a way to get the mouse position. So I have implemented a workaround to control the mouse with absolute values. Im resetting the mouse at start to 0/0 and after that Im buffering the actual position.